# How do I install docker on RHEL 7 offline?

Tags: rhel, docker

New to docker.

Current system configuration:
Dell R630 with RHEL 7.3 containing minimal installation

Requirement:
Need to install docker

1. How do I install docker on a system with no internet connectivity due to it being in a closed-network laboratory.

I hope I've made my request as simple as possible, let the questions begin.

Comment: No, Docker does not come with RHEL. You will have to add a Docker Repo in order to get Docker, in which case it won't come from Redhat.

Comment: Why would someone downvote my question? Is it not a helpful question for the community?

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are for not showing any research effort (see mouseover text). Also, your question is unclear: it doesn't make sense that you would want to install software that mostly relies on having network access while being offline. You'd need to be connected to the Internet to ensure the base images are kept up-to-date. Providing more detail/context would make this a more useful question. It also doesn't help to have two questions merged into one.

Comment: I've modified the question - hoping it becomes more useful to the community.

Comment: The only way I can think of is having a mirror which is *either* connected to the internet *or* to your lab. Or use RHEL Atomic Host, which comes with Docker installed. Side Question: How do you intent to load images?

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson It does come with Docker, just not preinstalled or being present on the installer image.

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg ; AFAIK, Red hat does not have Docker in any one of their official repo's(At least the updated stable version). One has to setup official Docker repo's to get the latest stable Docker EE.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson https://access.redhat.com/articles/2317361

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Great, nice update! `Updated November 30 2017`

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson It was just the latest update. Docker has been in “extras” for at least half a year (We were using it in production at least since then.)

Comment: I have done my installation in RHEL 7 and CentOS 7 using below guide.
https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/how-to-install-docker-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-and-centos-linux-7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

1Q. Does the RHEL 7 installation come with docker already on it? If not, where do I get it from? (I cannot use the docker software at docker.com, it has to come from RedHat - government rules, not mine)

1A. Based off of Hunter's comment, No, docker does not come with Red Hat; however, on a internet-connected system you can use the **reposync** command to download all of the RPMs from the RH Extras Channel using repoID: rhel-7-server-extras-rpms. Then by creating the repo data using **createrepo** command in the directory that contains the Packages directory. A good instruction set can be found [here](https://www.slashroot.in/yum-repository-and-package-management-complete-tutorial). Then you can transfer the data to the air-gapped system.

2Q. Once procured, how do I install it on a system that is not connected to the internet.

2A. Once you transfer the data RH Extras RPM data to the air-gapped system with minimal installation, you will need to install the some back-end tools: yum, yum-utils, and createrepo. [Here](https://teknoteknik.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/create-your-own-local-repository-and-solve-yum-related-problems/) is a good instruction set on how to do this. Once you get those tools installed you should be able to follow these instructions [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/installing-docker-centos-7-rhel-fedora-21-ganesh-kumar-sukumaran) to get docker installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably install the Centos 7 RPMs.
[From the instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/centos/) section "Install from a package":

> If you cannot use Docker’s repository to install Docker, you can
>   download the .rpm file for your release and install it manually. You
>   will need to download a new file each time you want to upgrade Docker.

The RPMs are hosted here:
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/

Comment: my question stated that docker MUST come from RH not Docker.com, thanks anyways.